# How to add transition effect when content changes in react using CSSTransition

Tags: css, reactjs, animation

```html
const Component = () => {
    const [newName, setnewName] = useState('');
    
      const updateName = (max: number) => {
  //logic to update newName
  };
  return (
    <>
    
            <div>{newName}</div>
          
       
    </>
  );
};
export default Component;
```

When ever the newName variable's value changes I want to add some effect in the ui for it. Is there any way that this can be done?

Comment: You can trigger an animation by adding a CSS class to the div. There are also libraries that auto-animate state changes, for example: https://auto-animate.formkit.com

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use the useEffect hook to achieve this, and add the newName state as a dependency.

For example, take a look at the following. I will demonstrate through `console.log("hey, newName changed")` every time the variable state changes.

```js
const Component = () => {
    const [newName, setnewName] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {console.log("hey, newName changed!"}, [newName])
    
  const updateName = (max: number) => {

  };
  return (
    <>
    
            <div>{newName}</div>
          
       
    </>
  );
};
export default Component;
```

Import it with useState.

Now, you may ask "yes, but youre only consoling something out, not actually doing anything with the CSS transition". Rest assured, you can take a similar approach.

The useEffect hook is simply a function that watches for state change. From the callback function, just add your custom css transition class, or fire a function that changes the CSS.

As I am not sure what kind of transition effect you want as you did not specify it in your question, so forgive me for not being able to provide a specific example. I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

use useEffect and dependancy in to change state and using that state you can update class, and then write aniamtion css for that class , hope this will help...

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
    const [newName, setnewName] = React.useState('Lorem');
    const [transition, setTransition] = React.useState(false)

    React.useEffect(()=>{
       setnewName('ipsum')
       setTransition(true)
    },[newName])

  return ( 
   <>
    <h1 classNane={`${transition?'animate':''}`} >{newName}</h1>
   </>
  );
}

export default App;
```